# Bash: Variable substitution in quoted string looks like something from the Twilight Zone

Tags: linux, bash, variables, printf

I've got a bash script that's reading essentially the output of telnet (actually socat to a unix domain socket).

```
while read -r LINE; do
    if [ "$USER_DATA_FLAG" == "true" ]; then   #Evaluates to false for the moment
        ...
    else
        printf "%s\n" "Variable> $LINE" >>$DEBUG_LOG
        printf "%s\n" "Line  xxxxz $LINE yxxxxx" >>$DEBUG_LOG
        ...
    fi
done
```

This yields the following incomprehensible output:

```
Variable> >INFO:OpenVPN Management Interface Version 1 -- type 'help' for more info
yxxxxxxxxz >INFO:OpenVPN Management Interface Version 1 -- type 'help' for more info
Variable> OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
yxxxxxxxxz OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
```

The first printf statement works fine and shows exactly what I expect based on my experience at the terminal. But the second printf statement goes nuts, reverses the order of some the characters and prints $LINE entirely in the wrong place!

Comment: Why are you using `printf` just to add a newline?

Comment: "%s\n" is a string and a newline, did I miss something?

Comment: It just seems like using a sledgehammer to kill a fly...

Comment: Echo produces the same result, I switched because I thought echo might be causing the issue.

Comment: echo "VARIABLE> $LINE" >> $DEBUG_LOG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$LINE` has a `\r` in it, which is sending the cursor back to column 1. Use parameter substitution or `tr` to remove it.

```
$ foo=$'1\r23'
$ echo "$foo"
23
$ echo "${foo/$'\r'/}"
123
```

Comment: Oi! Brilliant, that indeed fixed the problem, and with Einstein level simplicity, and so ends another great episode of the twilight zone. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This will ramble on a bit.  The first thing I noticed was this:

```
printf "%s\n" "Variable> $LINE" >>$DEBUG_LOG
```

And I immediately think, "this is C code."  In shell programming, `printf` is somewhat an odd tool which is sometimes useful, unlike the `printf` in C, which is the first thing you reach for when your printing something out.  Try this instead:

```
echo "Variable> $LINE" >>$DEBUG_LOG
```

The other problem is potentially with **telnet**.  If you parse telnet output in a shell, you're going to get some characters you don't want -- carriage returns, for example.  The default value of `IFS` for `bash` is `<space><tab><newline>`, which will NOT catch carriage returns and the carriage returns WILL mess with the location of characters in your terminal.

Ideally, you would get a proper telnet client and use it non-interactively.  However, in a pinch, you can do this:

```
while tr -d '\r' | read -r LINE; do
    ...
```

This will strip out carriage returns -- but there could still be other telnet junk in there, including  WILL/WONT/DO/DONT commands, and NUL bytes.

Comment: echo produces the same result (an article on bash pitfalls recommends printf over echo due to some issues with it interpreting parameters in $LINE). I think your second point is most likely, but I can't figure out how to identify what control characters I might be interpreting. Also a comparison of $LINE with the string it contains always fails inexplicably, also supporting the theory that extra control characters exist.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing and posting as I was thinking.  Answer should be more or less complete now.

Comment: use `xxd` or `od` to find what's actually in that telnet output

Comment: @David: The warning against `echo` does not apply in this case.  It only applies to `echo $var`, not `echo "some prefix $var"`.

Comment: I see that now. thanks! :)  What telnet client would you suggest? I'm connecting to the telnet management interface of OpenVPN which is listening on a unix domain socket. socat is what came up when I googled for this, but it seems like I've got some issues there. I'm playing with your suggestions now. Thanks!!

Comment: @David: The BSD telnet supports connecting to Unix domain sockets.  I haven't tried automating it, but you could try hooking stdin / stdout to fifos.  Or you could try `expect`, which is designed to do this kind of automation.